# I want to take a dictionary as input like roll and cgpa of a student after taking it i want to sort the value only not the key

Tags: python-3.x

I want to take a dictionary as input like roll and CGPA of a student after taking it i want to sort the value not the key

```
dic={}  
n=True   
while n:
      input("Insert roll: ")    
      cgpa=input("Insert Your cgpa: ")     
      dic[roll]=cgpa    
      repeat=input("Want To add more? :")    
      if repeat=='no':    
          n=False        


for roll, cgpa in dic.items():    
     print("\n"+roll+" : "+cgpa)   
sorted_d = dict(sorted(dic.items(), roll=lambda kv:kv[0] ))     
     print(sorted_d)
```

**input:**

```
1:3    
2:4.5     
3:4      
4:4.2
```

**output:**

```
2:4.5      
4:4.2     
3:4     
1:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the following dictionary:

```
c = {'1': 3, '2': 4.5, '3': 4, '4':  4.2}
```

Use the following code to sort in Descending order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
sorted_c = sorted(c.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
output = OrderedDict(sorted_c)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('2', 4.5), ('4', 4.2), ('3', 4), ('1', 3)])

>>> for k, v in output.items():
...     print(k,v)
...
('2', 4.5)
('4', 4.2)
('3', 4)
('1', 3)
```

This dictionary will behave the same as python dictionary. You can change the order by removing the `reverse` flag.

But be careful of your requirements. Dictionary has nothing to do with key order. If you look as the implementation and usage of dict, its made independent of order. Maybe you would want to switch to list to retain order and make use of that. BTW `sorted_c` is ordered list you might prefer.

Comment: I want to take the dictionary as input

Comment: that however doesn't make a difference. Just paste the code after the while loop and rename the variable ```c``` to ```dic```